# Solving ODE pendulum system with C and the GSL libary yields erroneous results for part of the answer then is correct

Tags: c, physics, ode, gsl, runge-kutta

When I implement the following code, I get wrong answers for maybe the first dozen or two runs, and then the system hits a maximum and seems to be accurate.  This is a simple dampened pendulum.  The code in question follows:

```
struct params{
    double g;
    double length;
    double damping;
    double startPosition;
    int startVelocity;
};

int func(double t, const double y[], double f[], void *params){
    (void) (t);
    struct params *init  = (struct params*)params;
    // Starting velocity
    f[0] = y[1];
    // Free Fall
    f[1] = -(init->damping)*y[1] - (init->g / init->length)*sin(y[0]);
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

int main(){
    // Paramter initialization
    struct params *inputs = malloc(sizeof(struct params));
    
    if (inputs != NULL){
        inputs->g=9.8;
        inputs->length=2;
        inputs->damping=0.1;
        inputs->startPosition = 0.2;
        inputs->startVelocity = 0;
    }

    int i;
    double t = 0.0, t1 = 100;
    double dt = 1;
    const int step_total = 101;

    double* timeX = malloc(step_total*sizeof(double));
    double* yOne = malloc(step_total*sizeof(double));
    double* yTwo = malloc(step_total*sizeof(double));

    clock_t start_time = clock(); //Record Start Time
    double timeout = 5.0; // Timeout in seconds

    int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 720;


    // System initialization
    gsl_odeiv2_system system = {func, NULL, 2, inputs};

    // ODE solver initialization
    const gsl_odeiv2_step_type *type = gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd;
    gsl_odeiv2_step *step = gsl_odeiv2_step_alloc(type, 2);
    gsl_odeiv2_control *control = gsl_odeiv2_control_y_new(1e-6,0.0);
    gsl_odeiv2_evolve *evolve = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_alloc(2);

    double y[2] = {inputs->startPosition, inputs->startVelocity};

    //printf ( " Step method is '%s'\n", gsl_odeiv2_step_name(step));
    i = 0; 
    while(t < t1){

        int status = gsl_odeiv2_evolve_apply(evolve, control, step, &system, &t, t1, &dt, y);
        
        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS){
            printf("error, return value=%d\n", status);
            break;
        }
        //if (y[0] <= 0) break;
        //printf("At time t=%.3f s, position=%.3f m, velocity=%.3f m/s\n", t, y[0], y[1]);
        timeX[i] = t;
        yOne[i] = y[0];
        yTwo[i] = y[1];
        i++;


        clock_t current_time = clock();
        double elapsed_time = (double)(current_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        if (elapsed_time > timeout){
            printf(" Infinite loop timeout reached. \n");
            break;
        } 

    }
    int total = i-1;
    i = 0;
    gsl_odeiv2_evolve_reset(evolve);
    gsl_odeiv2_control_free(control);
    gsl_odeiv2_step_free(step);
    gsl_odeiv2_evolve_free(evolve);
```

When I output the results in an array this is what I see: If you look at the first dozen or so output lines you can tell that my initial values are not correct for position and velocity.  Where does the system find the initial position of 73.609? Starting velocity is close to zero so that may be accurate. Once the position hits 100. Then the results look accurate and can be plotted.

```
At time t=0.575 s, position=73.609 m, velocity=0.004 m/s
At time t=1.185 s, position=74.530 m, velocity=0.000 m/s
At time t=1.721 s, position=75.452 m, velocity=-0.004 m/s
At time t=2.257 s, position=76.375 m, velocity=0.003 m/s
At time t=2.792 s, position=77.298 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=3.326 s, position=78.221 m, velocity=-0.004 m/s
At time t=3.910 s, position=79.166 m, velocity=0.003 m/s
At time t=4.499 s, position=80.111 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=5.088 s, position=81.056 m, velocity=-0.003 m/s
At time t=5.637 s, position=82.017 m, velocity=0.002 m/s
At time t=6.185 s, position=82.978 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=6.772 s, position=83.939 m, velocity=-0.003 m/s
At time t=7.371 s, position=84.919 m, velocity=0.002 m/s
At time t=7.970 s, position=85.899 m, velocity=0.000 m/s
At time t=8.525 s, position=86.879 m, velocity=-0.002 m/s
At time t=9.080 s, position=87.884 m, velocity=0.002 m/s
At time t=9.686 s, position=88.889 m, velocity=-0.001 m/s
At time t=10.296 s, position=89.894 m, velocity=-0.001 m/s
At time t=10.905 s, position=90.899 m, velocity=0.002 m/s
At time t=11.532 s, position=91.924 m, velocity=-0.001 m/s
At time t=12.158 s, position=92.949 m, velocity=-0.000 m/s
At time t=12.803 s, position=93.974 m, velocity=0.002 m/s
At time t=13.449 s, position=95.020 m, velocity=-0.002 m/s
At time t=14.094 s, position=96.067 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=14.739 s, position=97.114 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=15.384 s, position=98.161 m, velocity=-0.001 m/s
At time t=16.029 s, position=99.233 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=16.675 s, position=100.000 m, velocity=0.000 m/s
At time t=17.320 s, position=0.071 m, velocity=-0.103 m/s
At time t=17.965 s, position=-0.033 m, velocity=-0.163 m/s
At time t=18.618 s, position=-0.075 m, velocity=0.054 m/s
At time t=19.271 s, position=0.013 m, velocity=0.166 m/s
At time t=19.937 s, position=0.074 m, velocity=-0.015 m/s
At time t=20.602 s, position=0.002 m, velocity=-0.158 m/s
At time t=21.268 s, position=-0.068 m, velocity=-0.016 m/s
At time t=21.934 s, position=-0.015 m, velocity=0.145 m/s
At time t=22.600 s, position=0.061 m, velocity=0.042 m/s
At time t=23.266 s, position=0.026 m, velocity=-0.127 m/s
At time t=23.931 s, position=-0.052 m, velocity=-0.064 m/s
At time t=24.603 s, position=-0.033 m, velocity=0.108 m/s
At time t=25.275 s, position=0.044 m, velocity=0.077 m/s
At time t=25.950 s, position=0.038 m, velocity=-0.089 m/s
At time t=26.625 s, position=-0.035 m, velocity=-0.085 m/s
At time t=27.305 s, position=-0.040 m, velocity=0.071 m/s
At time t=27.986 s, position=0.028 m, velocity=0.089 m/s
At time t=28.673 s, position=0.041 m, velocity=-0.057 m/s
At time t=29.361 s, position=-0.022 m, velocity=-0.088 m/s
At time t=30.056 s, position=-0.040 m, velocity=0.046 m/s
At time t=30.751 s, position=0.018 m, velocity=0.085 m/s
At time t=31.455 s, position=0.038 m, velocity=-0.039 m/s
At time t=32.158 s, position=-0.016 m, velocity=-0.081 m/s
At time t=32.870 s, position=-0.035 m, velocity=0.036 m/s
At time t=33.581 s, position=0.015 m, velocity=0.075 m/s
At time t=34.299 s, position=0.033 m, velocity=-0.035 m/s
At time t=35.017 s, position=-0.015 m, velocity=-0.068 m/s
At time t=35.741 s, position=-0.030 m, velocity=0.036 m/s
At time t=36.465 s, position=0.016 m, velocity=0.062 m/s
At time t=37.193 s, position=0.027 m, velocity=-0.037 m/s
At time t=37.922 s, position=-0.017 m, velocity=-0.054 m/s
At time t=38.655 s, position=-0.023 m, velocity=0.040 m/s
At time t=39.388 s, position=0.018 m, velocity=0.046 m/s
At time t=40.126 s, position=0.020 m, velocity=-0.042 m/s
At time t=40.864 s, position=-0.019 m, velocity=-0.038 m/s
At time t=41.607 s, position=-0.016 m, velocity=0.044 m/s
At time t=42.349 s, position=0.020 m, velocity=0.029 m/s
At time t=43.099 s, position=0.011 m, velocity=-0.045 m/s
At time t=43.848 s, position=-0.020 m, velocity=-0.020 m/s
At time t=44.606 s, position=-0.007 m, velocity=0.045 m/s
At time t=45.364 s, position=0.020 m, velocity=0.009 m/s
At time t=46.135 s, position=0.002 m, velocity=-0.044 m/s
At time t=46.906 s, position=-0.019 m, velocity=0.003 m/s
At time t=47.676 s, position=0.003 m, velocity=0.040 m/s
At time t=48.447 s, position=0.017 m, velocity=-0.013 m/s
At time t=49.217 s, position=-0.008 m, velocity=-0.034 m/s
At time t=49.993 s, position=-0.014 m, velocity=0.021 m/s
At time t=50.768 s, position=0.011 m, velocity=0.025 m/s
At time t=51.561 s, position=0.009 m, velocity=-0.027 m/s
At time t=52.353 s, position=-0.013 m, velocity=-0.014 m/s
At time t=53.151 s, position=-0.004 m, velocity=0.030 m/s
At time t=53.949 s, position=0.013 m, velocity=0.001 m/s
At time t=54.760 s, position=-0.002 m, velocity=-0.028 m/s
At time t=55.570 s, position=-0.012 m, velocity=0.011 m/s
At time t=56.381 s, position=0.007 m, velocity=0.021 m/s
At time t=57.194 s, position=0.008 m, velocity=-0.019 m/s
At time t=58.008 s, position=-0.010 m, velocity=-0.011 m/s
At time t=58.834 s, position=-0.003 m, velocity=0.023 m/s
At time t=59.661 s, position=0.010 m, velocity=-0.001 m/s
At time t=60.504 s, position=-0.003 m, velocity=-0.020 m/s
At time t=61.347 s, position=-0.008 m, velocity=0.012 m/s
At time t=62.190 s, position=0.007 m, velocity=0.012 m/s
At time t=63.045 s, position=0.003 m, velocity=-0.018 m/s
At time t=63.901 s, position=-0.008 m, velocity=-0.000 m/s
At time t=64.763 s, position=0.002 m, velocity=0.016 m/s
At time t=65.626 s, position=0.006 m, velocity=-0.010 m/s
At time t=66.488 s, position=-0.006 m, velocity=-0.009 m/s
At time t=67.366 s, position=-0.002 m, velocity=0.015 m/s
At time t=68.244 s, position=0.007 m, velocity=-0.003 m/s
At time t=69.134 s, position=-0.003 m, velocity=-0.012 m/s
```

Comment: What happens if you reduce your step size?

Comment: What you are calling your position isn't a position either from what I can see.  It's actually in radians.   Your equations I think will allow for a stable oscillation around any angle 2pin, n an integer.  I could believe you can end up there if the solver chases down weird paths (e.g. being given a large step size, bad initial conditions)

Comment: New Parameters @possum: 
```
   if (inputs != NULL){
        inputs->g=9.8;
        inputs->length=2;
        inputs->damping=0.5;
        inputs->startPosition = 2;
        inputs->startVelocity = 0;
    }
```
These new values improve the first bit of data to look like a pendelumn, then halfway through it resets and starts over in the second data set (position, velocity) respectively. Not sure why.
The step size dt = 0.01 doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: The reported behavior is not reproducible. Please change the code so that it exhibits the presented error behavior. This includes the headers that are included.

Comment: I was limited in how much code I could enter versus text explanations.  This code is part of an open source repo: https://github.com/DogIsGreat/TailWagging-/blob/main/src/pendelumviz.c